Is it possible to export an object, and have it look like a wireframe without subdivision surface applied?
I've got an object I created in blender. This is what it looks like, using the 'Solid' option under viewport shading (the top right corner of Blender):

And this is what it looks like, when I turn on the 'Wireframe' option:

What you see in the wireframe screenshot, is the wireframe of the object before I've applied the subdivision surface modifier - My goal is to export my object into an FBX file, and have it look exactly as it does in the second screenshot (or at least have it look close enough).
I know there's a wireframe modifier in blender, however after meddling with it's settings it always makes the wireframe with the subdivision surface modifier applied, which ends up looking like this:

I'm not sure if doing what I'm asking for is possible, but if someone could point me in the right direction, help would be greatly appreciated :-).
